# How to separate a special marker from a cluster in Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using Javascript Google Maps API V3.
There is a special marker in one cluster, but I want it always to be shown outside the cluster. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Well, I just find out solution by myself:  
    new MarkerClusterer(map, restMarkers, { //options });
    new MarkerClusterer(map, [specialMarker], { //options });

  map is a google.maps.Map object  
  restMarkers is an Arrary[] containing google.maps.Marker objects  
  specialMarker is a google.maps.Marker object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in the following way:

```
    // create your marker
    var marker = ....

    // mark your special marker
    var markerToRemove = marker;

    // create marker clusterer
    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      maxZoom: zoom,
      gridSize: size,
      styles: styles[style]
    });

    // remove your special marker from cluster
    markerClusterer.removeMarker(markerToRemove);

    // put it back on map
    markerToRemove.setMap(map);
```

The last step is necessary because MarkerClusterer `removeMarker()` function set map to `null` so marker is not visible any more.